# Postgres : Multiply length of array to count aggregate result

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

Following command works fine :

```
select count(*) * 2 from rooms;
```

But if I am trying to do something like :

```
select count(*) * array_length(students,1) from rooms;
```

where `students` is an array column in the table `rooms`. Following error is thrown :

```
ERROR: column "rooms.students" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
SQL state: 42803
Character: 32
```

What is the right way to get the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sum` was an obvious choice :

```
select sum(array_length(students,1)) from rooms;
```